# how to add an event in the angular range slider . i use ngchange but it is not working

Tags: angularjs, rangeslider

```
<div range-slider min="minPrice" max="maxPrice" modelmin="userMinPrice" model-max="userMaxPrice" step="5" ng-model="selectedPrice" ng-change="price()"></div>
```

how to fire an event when angular range slider value change and call a function.ngchange is not working.

Comment: If you are using this one https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider and looking at the docs I don't think 'range-slider' supports `ng-model` or `ng-change`

Comment: then what is the solution

Comment: You can add watches and if you want I can provide a demo code.

Comment: yes . i need demo code. can you please upload it??

Comment: Check out the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, check out below code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui-rangeSlider'])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {

    $scope.rangeSlider = {
      minPrice: 10,
      maxPrice: 100
    }

    $scope.userMinPrice = 50;
    $scope.userMaxPrice = 80;

    $scope.$watch('userMinPrice', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.message = 'userMinPrice has changed from ' + oldVal + ' to ' + newVal;
        // To whatever you want here.
      }
    });
    $scope.$watch('userMaxPrice', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.message = 'userMaxPrice has changed from ' + oldVal + ' to ' + newVal;;
        // To whatever you want here.
      }
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/angular.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/angular.rangeSlider.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <div range-slider min="rangeSlider.minPrice" max="rangeSlider.maxPrice" model-min="userMinPrice" model-max="userMaxPrice" step="5">
  </div>

  <div> {{ message }} </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```
<div 
     range-slider min="0" 
     max="100" 
     model-max="demo7.valueB"  
     pin-handle="min" 
     on-handle-up="choosePrice(demo7.valueB)">

     </div>
```

In controller section (js file)

$scope.demo7 = {
                    valueA: 0,
                    valueB: 25
                };

```
            $scope.choosePrice=function(val)
            {
                console.log(val);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution. use on-handle-up

```
<div range-slider min="minPrice" max="maxPrice" model-min="userMinPrice" model-max="userMaxPrice" step="5" ng-model="selectedPrice" filter="currency" on-handle-up="choosePrice()"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, that could also serve the purpose.